# Existence of a linear function from $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $D_n$ be the open disc of radius $n$ with centre at the point $(n,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Does there exist a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ of the form $f(x,y)=ax+by$ such that 
>   $$\cup_{n=1}^\infty D_n=\{(x,y)\mid f(x,y)>0\}\;?$$
>   If your answer is 'Yes', give the values of $a$ and $b$.

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V2wa.png))

The given set is open set, I think a function $f(x,y)=x$ or $y$ can do the job, but I am not sure, I also want to know whether inside the question any  deep result is hidden from analysis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $\cup_{n=1}^\infty D_n=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x>0\}$.

[image]

Comment: :How can values for $a$ & $b$ be determined??